# Error Last 5 orders Dashboard Missing Customer Name

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

Before a critical path update, i was missing the customers name on my dashboard BE.

ON

> adminhtml/block/dashboard/orders/grid.php

Here is the column with the fault on line 87:

```
$this->addColumn('customer', array(
    'header'    => $this->__('Customer'),
    'sortable'  => false,
    'index'     => 'customer',
    'default'   => $this->__('Guest'),
));
```

Now, it returns a white space.

What i should check?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you clarify the situation you're facing?

Comment: It's simple, my column Customer on '5 Last Orders' is always blank, but as i put my code, i wants to print is the customers name.

Comment: So, you have overridden the default Dashboard_Orders_Grid? Or, you're using the default core Dashboard_Orders_Grid & want to show names which are not showing.

Comment: Is those customer names are showing in Sales_Order_Grid?

Comment: I am using the default core dashboard_orders_grid , and the customers name display perfectly.
The problem in this column, is that must show default 'Guest' , because the last 5 orders are from not logged customers but it don't display nothing.
And yes, they are showing in sales_order_grid as customer or guest.

Comment: I think the code is perfect out there, but is the name column showing blank for guest customers rather than showing their names?

Comment: I think it too.
What? The column prints - 'Customer' as i put on header, but on each field, it never prints 'Guest' -> that is the correct output because all the last 5 orders are from guests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for the error, i can't reproduce where it is, so i manage the error with STYLE & JS:

> #lastOrdersGrid_table tbody td:empty:after {        content: 'Guest'    }

-

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll( '#lastOrdersGrid_table tbody td:first-child' );

Array.prototype.slice.call( cells ).forEach( function( cell ) {
    if ( cell.innerHTML == '&nbsp;' )
    {
        cell.innerHTML = '';
    }
});
```